# Typescript interface array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare and interface. Basically a user has a collection of roles. I am not able to understand what the right syntax in Typescript for this operation.

```
export interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    roles: [Role]
}

export interface Role {
    accountId: string;
    roleId: string;
}
```

Comment: `roles: Role[]` Have you tried, reading the docs on [Arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array), you can make a collection of something like so:

```js
export interface Role {
    accountId: string;
    roleId: string;
}

export interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    roles: Array<Role> // Can also be written as Role[]
}
```

(Additionally, I think roles and accountId should be kept separate.)

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```js
export interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    roles: Role[];
}
```